Kid's tv series with the uncle/grandfather which is android
I'm looking for the TV show for kid's which:

may come from 80'
may be not English language, but if English rather GB (the style of scenes, home)
mine role belonging to siblings which leave in at least 2 floor house; the uncle/grandfather was taking care of them
opening scene or intro contains the moment when the uncle was opening the dresser standing on the floor to get to a secret basement - kind of laboratory where he maitanance himself
other scene shows the moment of taking his head off


Does the uncle/grandfather have a extendable eye in the back part of his head? I think I remember something...

Yes, indeed there was something like that.

The series is called "Spuk von draußen" and is from the former GDR.
The Wikipedia entry Spuk von draußen is in German only, but it tells about the Grandpa whose name is "Rodenwald" and that he is the robot "RO-101".
I found the clue in the Planet3DNow forum, where a user also mentions the secret laboratory in the basement.
I think for this question you had to google in German :)

Yes it is. Thanks to the German title I found the Polish one, so I can explore it in the history of my television.
